# map em C funciona?

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar `map` em C. Eu sei que funciona em C++, mas em C sempre dá erro de compilação. Se alguém já usou map em C, poderia me mostrar como utilizar?

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    map<int, char[10]> m;

    m[1] = "Um";
    m[2] = "Dois";
    m[4] = "quatro";

   printf(m[4]); // não sei se precisa de mascara de dados
}
```

Comment: O tipo map não existe em C, apenas em C++. O que você poderia fazer é criar o seu próprio tipo `map`.

Comment: Do jeito que está acho que nem em C++ vai funcionar, você precisa escrever por exemplo `using namespace std;`, e a forma de inserção está errada, deveria ser usando o `insert()`.

Comment: Vlw Galera, já desconfiava que não funcionava em C. Acho que map só funciona em linguagens orientadas a objetos, eu já utilizei em java mas nunca tinha testado em C. Obrigado por responder.

Comment: Acho que você não precisa reinventar a roda. Já existem soluções similares em C. Vide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647054/porting-stdmap-to-c

Comment: Esse pessoal do stackoverflow na versão em inglês inventa cada implementação complexa rs, usando struct, ponteiro, alocação de memória, funcão recebendo ponteiro como parâmetro. Mas tá valendo não sabia que dava pra criar um map dessa forma em C.

Comment: Paulo, para exemplos como aquele que incluiste na pergunta, um **array** em C (que é um caso muito particular de map ), funciona perfeitamente...

Comment: @JJoao, dei uma olhada na documentação de C. E array só funciona em C++.

Answer (score 3):

Não funciona na linguagem C. O map é um recurso da linguagem C++ ([detalhes aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)), uma vez que utiliza recursos que não são encontrados no C e são característicos de orientação a objetos.

O que você pode fazer é encontrar alguma biblioteca que desempenhe uma função semelhante em C.

Comment: vlw pela resposta (y)

Comment: Tranquilo, @Paulo !

Answer (score 0):

Alguns maps resolvem-se perfeitamente com um array! Em relação ao teu exemplo,

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
    char *  m[20];

    m[1] = "Um";
    m[2] = "Dois";
    m[4] = "quatro";

   printf("%s\n", m[4]);
}
```

funciona perfeitamente.

Se os teus índices forem mais complexos (exemplo strings, etc) podes usar
Map implmentados com:

- tabelas de hash (ver `man hsearch`)
- árvores binárias de procura (ver `man tsearch`)
- array de pares (ver `man lsearch`)

ir para bibliotecas mais ricas como

- glib  (ver google glib)
- lib db   (para map em ficheiro,)

ou até ir para C++ (boost, etc)

Comment: Vlw @JJoao pela ajuda, e pelas opções disponíveis que vc me deu. Melhor fórum que existe sempre tem alguém disponível pra responder rs

Comment: Faltou alocar o m, senão não funciona.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura, o `m` é um vector `m[20]` de apontadores: portanto o `m` tem espaço próprio. Cada um dos apontadores vai precisar de apontar para um espaço "definido". Se usarmos `m[5]` como algo que vai sendo alterado, presisamoc de alocar espaço para essa string (ex `m[i]=malloc(50)`) se simplesmete tivermos um valor constante o C coloca essas constantes numa area de dados (a quando da compilação) e este caso não precisamos de mallocs.

Comment: o m é do tipo char**, sendo uma dimensão de tamanho definido (20); a outra dimensão não tem tamanho definido e por isso precisa ser alocada.

Comment: Não precisa, caso ele preencha com declarações como `m[2] = "Dois";`

Answer (score 0):

Como já sugerido o melhor é implementar sua estrutura de *map* nesse caso.
Posso recomendar o uso de [*hash table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) e a utilização [dessa *lib*](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/index.html) para C.

De uma olhada também [nesse artigo](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/summary.html) que explica sobre *hash table*.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda